# What is better, using @manytomany or create entity for intermediate table?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many, eclipselink

It is true that using the relationship manytomany is easier than presenting the intermediate table by an entity but I don't like this annotation for many raisons:

1. It's impossible to add a new columns in my intermediate table
2. matching the intermediate table by entity looks more close to the reality than using @ManyToMany

What do you think ?

Comment: It's not impossible to add new columns. You just need to change your mapping accordingly. Mapping a simple link table as an entity is unnecessary. Nobody's stopping you, but don't think that everyone shares your view of it "looking more close to reality". After all, ORM is an abstraction.

Comment: I want to montien that there is nothing intrinsically wrong with using @ManyToMany but in practice, I usually need additional attributes on the link itself, at which point, the relationship becomes an entity of its own. by changing the relationship, I should change the model too which can be costly, that's why I prefer to use the entity from the begining

Comment: Then go right ahead with your preference. Just don't expect it to be hailed as a universal truth here.

Comment: @kayaman I am not expecting that, just I want to have the opinion of the community

Answer (score 0):

It's a case to case basis.

1) There are occasions when a relationship actually has *"state"* associated with it. In the case of many-to-many relationship, if you want to add a state/property in your relationship, then you will need turn your relationship into a **separate entity**. Hence, this will result in new column(s) in your join table besides the foreign keys.
This requires updating your mappings. Here is a good example:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

*Technically, we are not using the `@ManyToMany` mapping here but logically it is many-to-many relationship. The new entity (relationship entity) will have a many-to-one relationship to each of the existing entity types, and each of the entity types will have a one-to-many relationship back to the new entity representing the relationship*

2) If maintaining a relationship *"state"* as mentioned in point #1 is not necessary, then a simple use of `@ManyToMany` association mapping should suffice. It eliminates the need to maintain/manage a separate entity just to represent the relationship. Otherwise, a separate entity will just complicate your object model.